# If statement with command button and change a cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to type code where if someone selects "admin" in cell A5, an input box for a password appears. If the password is wrong, I want the value in cell A5 to change to "user". There is also a certain command button that will appear if the person is "admin". My if statement does not seem to work. It stays at "admin" if the password is wrong.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'If user is selected, hide button. If admin is selected, enter password to see the button'
If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A5")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
If Range("A5") = "User" Then ActiveSheet.CommandButton1.Visible = False
If Range("A5") = "Admin" Then
    strwork = InputBox("Please enter Admin Password.")
    If strwork = "excel" Then ActiveSheet.CommandButton1.Visible = True
    
    ElseIf strwork <> "excel" Then
        MsgBox ("Incorrect Password")
        ActiveSheet.CommandButton1.Visible = False
        Range("A5") = "User"
       
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `ActiveSheet.CommandButton1.Visible = False And Range("A5") = "User"` this should be 2 separate lines of code, not And

Comment: Hi Nathan, I just tried that. It still stays at "Admin" value when password is wrong. And a msgbox of "Incorrect password" appears when I have "User" selected.

Comment: What happens if you use `Range("A5").Value = "User"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ElseIf strwork <> "excel" Then` relates to `If Range("A5") = "Admin" Then` because of writing `If strwork = "excel" Then ActiveSheet.CommandButton1.Visible = True` in one line. Try editing the code this way:

```
If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A5")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
If Range("A5") = "User" Then ActiveSheet.CommandButton1.Visible = False
If Range("A5") = "Admin" Then
     strwork = InputBox("Please enter Admin Password.")
     If strwork = "excel" Then 
         ActiveSheet.CommandButton1.Visible = True
     ElseIf strwork <> "excel" Then
         MsgBox ("Incorrect Password")
         ActiveSheet.CommandButton1.Visible = False
         Range("A5") = "User"
     End If
End If
```

And some code optimization:

```
If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A5")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
ActiveSheet.CommandButton1.Visible = False
If Range("A5") = "Admin" Then
     strwork = InputBox("Please enter Admin Password.")
     If strwork = "excel" Then 
         ActiveSheet.CommandButton1.Visible = True
     Else 
         MsgBox ("Incorrect Password")
         ActiveSheet.CommandButton1.Visible = False
         Range("A5") = "User"
     End If
End If
```

Comment: Is there a need for the 2nd `ActiveSheet.CommandButton1.Visible = False` ;o)